# mysql trigger to update the same table from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up a trigger which will update same row by inserting some additional data from another table. Field receive.iccid is blank, and I want it to be updated on every insert. However this trigger doesn't work

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER ins_iccid 
AFTER INSERT ON receive 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE receive SET NEW.iccid = (SELECT goip.iccid FROM goip WHERE NEW.goipname=goip.name);
END// 

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Ever thought about what will happen, if you change a `name` in the `goip` table?

Comment: i already figured it out by using BEFORE INSERT statement instead

Answer (score 1):

turns out that I need to use 'BEFORE INSERT' to achieve what i was trying to

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `ins_iccid` BEFORE INSERT ON `receive`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
    SET NEW.iccid = (SELECT goip.iccid FROM goip WHERE NEW.goipname=goip.name);
 END
```